# Dovecot saves incoming mail from LMTP in wrong home directory despite being correctly overwritten

Tags: dovecot, openldap

I have setup Postfix 3.8.1, Dovecot 2.3.20 and OpenLDAP on Ubuntu 23.10. Postfix transfers mails for local delivery via LMTP to Dovecot. In some cases, the mail address as seen from the outside world (e.g. `user-local-mail-part@some-domain.tld`) and the the user name as used for SASL authentication and for home directories do not match. Nonetheless, SASL and usernames also follow the pattern `user-name@some-domain.tld` to separate user names between different virtual hosted domain.

The LDAP entry looks like this

```
dn: uid=user-name, ou=users, o=some-domain.tld, dc=mailserver, dc=server-domain, dc=tld
uid: user-name
mailAccount: user-local-mail-part@some-domain.tld
```

Postfix delivers a mail as `user-local-mail-part@some-domain.tld` to Dovecot, because this its mail address. However, Dovevot must store this mail in `/var/spool/mail/vmail/some-domain.tld/user-name/` because that is the user's virtual mail home directory.

However, Dovecots puts the mail which are received via LMTP from Postfix erroneously into `/var/spool/mail/vmail/some-domain.tld/user-local-mail-part/`. Consequently, the mails are not found when the user logs in via IMAP.

My Dovecot config

```
root@mailserver:~ # cat /etc/dovecot/conf.d/auth-ldap.conf.ext 

passdb {
  driver = ldap

  # Path for LDAP configuration file, see example-config/dovecot-ldap.conf.ext
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap-passdb.conf.ext
}
userdb {
  driver = ldap
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap-userdb.conf.ext
  default_fields = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/spool/mail/vmail/%d/%n
}
```

```
root@mailserver:~ # cat /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap-passdb.conf.ext 

uris = ldapi:///var/run/slapd/ldapi
auth_bind = yes
auth_bind_userdn = uid=%n,ou=users,o=%d,dc=mailserver,dc=server-domain,dc=tld
base = ou=users,o=%d,dc=mailserver,dc=server-domain,dc=tld
```

```
root@mailserver:~ # cat /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap-userdb.conf.ext 

uris   = ldapi:///var/run/slapd/ldapi
dn     = uid=dovecot,ou=users,o=mailserver.server-domain.tld,dc=mailserver,dc=server-domain,dc=tld
dnpass = dovecot
base   = ou=users,o=%d,dc=h2917298,dc=stratoserver,dc=net
# Change user to uid (suffixed with domain) regardless whether the user
# was found by uid or mailAccount, see
# https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/authentication/ldap_backend_configuration/
user_attrs = \
  =user=%{ldap:uid}@%d \
  =home=/var/spool/mail/vmail/%d/%{ldap:uid}
user_filter = (&(objectClass=mailAccount)(|(uid=%n)(mailAccount=%u)))
```

The mail logs are

```
mailserver.server-domain.tld postfix/smtpd[352703]: connect from mout02.posteo.de[185.67.36.66]
mailserver.server-domain.tld postfix/smtpd[352703]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mout02.posteo.de[185.67.36.66]: TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (256/256 bits) key-exchange X25519 server-signature EC>
mailserver.server-domain.tld policyd-spf[352708]: : prepend Received-SPF: Pass (mailfrom) identity=mailfrom; client-ip=185.67.36.66; helo=mout02.posteo.de; envelope-from=sender@posteo.de; receiver=some-domain.tld
mailserver.server-domain.tld postfix/smtpd[352703]: EA8098130E: client=mout02.posteo.de[185.67.36.66]
mailserver.server-domain.tld postfix/cleanup[352709]: EA8098130E: message-id=<5725552.DvuYhMxLoT@posteo>
mailserver.server-domain.tld postfix/qmgr[350847]: EA8098130E: from=<sender@posteo.de>, size=2026, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
mailserver.server-domain.tld postfix/smtpd[352703]: disconnect from mout02.posteo.de[185.67.36.66] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=7
mailserver.server-domain.tld dovecot[352659]: lmtp(352711): Connect from local
mailserver.server-domain.tld dovecot[352659]: lmtp(user-name@some-domain.tld =home=/var/spool/mail/vmail/some-domain.tld/user-name)<352711><3soFD7lgRmXHYQUAg2lwgA>: msgid=<5725552.DvuYhMxLoT@posteo>: saved mail to INBOX
mailserver.server-domain.tld postfix/lmtp[352710]: EA8098130E: to=<user-local-mail-part@some-domain.tld>, relay=mailserver.server-domain.tld[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.37, delays=0.36/0.01/0.01/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <>
mailserver.server-domain.tld dovecot[352659]: lmtp(352711): Disconnect from local: Logged out (state=READY)
mailserver.server-domain.tld postfix/qmgr[350847]: EA8098130E: removed
```

Note: Posteo is the mail service which I use to send test mails to my mail server.

The 9th line reads

```
dovecot[352659]: lmtp(user-name@some-domain.tld =home=/var/spool/mail/vmail/some-domain.tld/user-name)<...><...>: msgid=<...@posteo>: saved mail to INBOX
```

and the 10th line is

```
postfix/lmtp[352710]: EA8098130E: to=<user-local-mail-part@some-domain.tld>, relay=mailserver.server-domain.tld[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.37, delays=0.36/0.01/0.01/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <>
```

This actually looks as if re-writing would happen the way it is supposed to happen. Postfix delivers the mail for `user-local-mail-part@some-domain.tld`, but Dovecot knows the user is `user-name@some-domain.tld` with home directory `/var/spool/mail/vmail/some-domain.tld/user-name`.

Nonetheless, the mail is saved as

```
root@mailserver:~ # find /var/spool/mail/vmail/ -name 'u.?'
/var/spool/mail/vmail/some-domain.tld/user-local-mail-part/Maildir/mailboxes/INBOX/dbox-Mails/u.2
/var/spool/mail/vmail/some-domain.tld/user-local-mail-part/Maildir/mailboxes/INBOX/dbox-Mails/u.3
/var/spool/mail/vmail/some-domain.tld/user-local-mail-part/Maildir/mailboxes/INBOX/dbox-Mails/u.1
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

It was a trivial oversight and a missing comma.

Instead of

```
root@mailserver:~ # cat /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap-userdb.conf.ext 

user_attrs = \
  =user=%{ldap:uid}@%d \
  =home=/var/spool/mail/vmail/%d/%{ldap:uid}
user_filter = (&(objectClass=mailAccount)(|(uid=%n)(mailAccount=%u)))
```

it should have been

```
root@mailserver:~ # cat /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap-userdb.conf.ext 

user_attrs = \
  =user=%{ldap:uid}@%d, \   ### <-- COMMA WAS MISSING HERE
  =home=/var/spool/mail/vmail/%d/%{ldap:uid}
user_filter = (&(objectClass=mailAccount)(|(uid=%n)(mailAccount=%u)))
```

Due to the missing comma, only the `user` variable was set. Hence, Dovecot did not complain that it could find the user. But the `home` variable remained unset.

Sometimes, I hate Linux daemons ;-) Instead of complaining that the config file was invalid, Dovecot simply ignored the line with `=home ...` after the missing comma.